# how to specify a bean as non lazy with annotations

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-annotations

Does anyone know how to specify a bean as *non* lazy when using annotations to configure the bean?

Comment: Beans are non-lazy by default. Are you overriding this default in your context?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beans are not lazy by default. However as far as annotations are concerned it seems like currently annotations do not support it. 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=62931

Spring's next version though seem to have something in store 
http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SJC-263

Answer (score 35):

In spring 3.0 there is an annotation: [`@Lazy(false)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html). But note that beans are eager by default.

Answer (score 9):

Just to set things straight, be known that as to Spring 3.0 and later, beans are by default eagerly initialized.

Excerpt from the [`@Lazy(false)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) link in Bozho's answer:

> **If this annotation is not present on a Component or Bean definition,
>   eager initialization will occur.** If present and set to true, the
>   Bean/Component will not be initialized until referenced by another
>   bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory. If
>   present and set to false, the bean will be instantiated on startup by
>   bean factories that perform eager initialization of singletons.

Answer (score -3):

I tried @EnableScheduling in my Configuration Annotation class and that did the trick.